# super slow opencv cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://) python

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp, ip-camera

im trying to read a IP camera stream trought rtps.
I can open the stream inside opencv but its stremly slow and its generating a huge delay from real movement and screen movment.

there is my code ( its simple )

```
import cv2
stream = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://root:root@192.168.0.2/media.amp')
while True:
    frame = stream.read()
    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Which Operating System are you using? Mac OS?

Comment: linux, in a raspberry p4 raspibian and in my note ubuntu 20

Comment: I see the same. Did you ever get to the bottom of it.
One thing I see is that there's sometimes a 10 seconds or more delay before opencv opens a TCP connection to the rtsp service.
I suspect its doing some internal search for an rtsp client library, maybe.